# Define controller method as form action

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a following code

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'clientController@create')); !!}
```

it shouts that clientController@create is not defined unless I put some code into routes.php (this is my solution)

```
Route::post('clientRegistration', ['uses' => 'clientController@create', 'as' => 'registration']);
```

Everything then works fine, but I am not sure if I have found the correct solution, do I have to create a route for every form that will be created? I don't know why Laravel could not find a controller method without registering it in routes.php file

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ClientController@create`?

Comment: Why it should be? camelCase naming always starts with lower case character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling an action Laravel searches through it's stored route to handler associations. This is done in `routes.php`

If you insert

```
Route::post('clientRegistration', ['uses' => 'clientController@create', 'as' => 'registration']);
```

in your `routes.php` you can do any of the following

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'registration')); !!}
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'clientController@create')); !!}
```

If you only stick with

```
Route::post('clientRegistration', 'clientController@create');
```

you can still use

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'clientController@create')); !!}
```

More information here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

No matter what, you will need to inform Laravel about your route in `routes.php`, because otherwise it will not know how to handle the request.

I suggest

```
Route::resource('client', 'ClientController');
```

Please read 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes